# No module named 'discord

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Пытаюсь запустить файл .py , но не может найти модуль

`File "C:/Users/****/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 2, in import discord`

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'

`import discord`

discord.py установлена и так же переустанавливал

Comment: Почитайте про окружения питона. Вероятно, у вас установлено несколько версий питона и запускаете вы не ту версию, в которую установили библиотеку.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй `import discord.py`

У тебя компилятор жалуется на то, что он не может найти библиотеку `discord`, хотя, на самом деле, ее нет! Я так понимаю ты имел ввиду библиотеку `discord.py`